# Dynamic URL for XMLhttprequest

Tags: javascript, html, api

I used news API to get news content via json format. 
I have html 'input element' which user can select for multiple sources.
what i wanted is if the source is equal to "user selected source or define" then the news content will change according to user selection.

As you can see i don't use jQuery i need to be more comfortable with JS than jQuery for now. so i prefer working with pure JS.

My newsapi: https://newsapi.org

this is my code.
that's working without the user selection functionality.

HTML:

```
<!--dropDown Category-->
<div class="form-group" id="categorySelector">
      <label for="newsCat">Select source:</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="newsCat">                              
                <option value="the-next-web">the-next-web</option>
                 <option value="wired-de">wired-de</option>
                 <option value="time">time</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
   var newsRequest,
    newsKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    newsSource = 'the-next-web'; //defaultSource
//for older broswser
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    newsRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    newsRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} //window.XMLHttpRequest    

newsRequest.open("GET", 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + newsSource + '&sortBy=latest&apiKey=' + newsKey);
newsRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ((newsRequest.readyState === 4) && (newsRequest.status === 200)) {
        var infoNews = JSON.parse(newsRequest.responseText);
        // Action to be performed when the document is read;

        var newsHtml = '<ul class="list-group">';
        for (var i = 0; i < infoNews.articles.length; i++) {
            newsHtml += '<li>';
            newsHtml += '<div class="newItem">' + '<a href="' + infoNews.articles[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + '<img src = "' + infoNews.articles[i].urlToImage + '"  alt="' + infoNews.articles[i].title + '" title="' + infoNews.articles[i].title + '">' + '</a>';
            newsHtml += '<h3 class="newsTitle">' + infoNews.articles[i].title + '</h3>';
            newsHtml += '<p class="newsDes">' + infoNews.articles[i].description + '</p>';
            newsHtml += '<p class="newsAuthor">' + infoNews.articles[i].author + '</p>';
            newsHtml += '</div>';
            newsHtml += '</li>';
        } //for loops json
        newsHtml += '</ul>';
        document.querySelector('.newsParent').innerHTML = newsHtml;


    } //newsRequest.readyState
} //newsRequest.readyState
//xmlhtpprequest method open                   
newsRequest.send();
```

//i came up with this code..
document.querySelector('#newsCat').onchange = function(selectedSource){
     newsSource = selectedSource.value;  // by this is still not good because this inside a function
}

Comment: And why don't you want to use it inside of function? Setting up an event callback for onChange would be the best idea I can think of.

Comment: yes, that's possible.  but i still hard time to figure out to change this URL dynamicly. newsRequest.open("GET", 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + newsSource + '&sortBy=latest&apiKey=' + newsKey);  I want the newSource to be dynamic. I have created a function in call it via above url but the result is https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + function{ bla.bla}+ '&sortBy=latest&apiKey=' + newsKey)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `onchange` callback sent from the `select` element.
First we want to hook up `onchange` event to some method, so we add `onchange="selectionChanged()"` attribute to the `<select>` tag.

In the method `selectionChange` we will handle the changes:
Get `newsCat` element and if it is not null (it can be, before window is loaded) we are getting it's value. Finally we're passing this value to the `getNewsFromApi` method which actually uses this value, to build api url and get the data from external source.

```js
var newsKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

function selectionChanged() {
  var categorySelect = document.getElementById('newsCat');
  var selectedCategory = categorySelect !== null ? categorySelect.value : 'the-next-web';
    
  getNewsFromApi(selectedCategory);
}
  
function getNewsFromApi(newsSource) {
  var apiUrl = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + newsSource + '&sortBy=latest&apiKey=' + newsKey;
  
  // here goes your API call
  
  console.log('getting news from: ' + apiUrl);
}

getNewsFromApi('the-next-web');
```

```html
    <div class="form-group" id="categorySelector">
      <label for="newsCat">Select source:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="newsCat" onchange="selectionChanged()">                              
        <option value="the-next-web">the-next-web</option>
        <option value="wired-de">wired-de</option>
        <option value="time">time</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: I used your code in it works, can you please explain a bit to me about your code?